# DS-160 Validity/Expiry

Tags: visas, usa

I have read that the DS-160 (Non-immigrant visa application for the US) expires after 30 days. This is probably true for applications that are not yet submitted, so that they get purged from the system after that duration.

However, is the same true for submitted applications?

My worry is the following:
Suppose I fill out a DS-160, submit it, and use it to schedule a consulate visa interview say **2 months out**. Will the system automatically delete the DS-160 30 days after the date of scheduling, such that the consulate officer cannot retrieve the form? Or is such a worry unjustified?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only "30 day" period that I am aware of is that the DS-160 website will delete an **unsubmitted** application after 30 days of **inactivity**.

This 30 day period does not apply :

- To an application once it has been submitted, or
- To an application when saved locally to your computer (it will still expire from the website after 30 days, but you can upload it and continue after that time)

Having more than 30 days between submitting an application and attending an interview will definitely not be a problem.

Comment: To complement the information above, except for countries with massive backlogs, a **submitted** DS-160 will be valid for 365 days after submission.